# How to trust link between application session and OIDC refresh token

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, openid

I have a web application that has its own session (sessionid cookie, timing out after 60mins). The user logs in via an OIDC connection and we store the idtoken and accesstoken on the session server-side, the refreshtoken in a cookie. We use "email" from the /userinfo endpoint to start a session with the backoffice application.

After x minutes, user comes back and we find idtoken and accesstoken expired. We do a refresh on the /token endpoint to get new accesstoken, but some OIDC servers do not return a new idtoken (still not sure why).

So, when I don't get a new idtoken I don't have a valid one anymore. Can I then simply trust that the idtoken belongs to the current session (as I cannot validate if my current session is for the same sub as the OIDC session), or should I ask for re-login on the auth server?

Comment: If you are refreshing an access token via a direct HTTP POST to a trusted URL, then you don't need to do anything with ID tokens, as Hans indicates. I suspect your issue is client libraries that make incorrect assumptions. Aim to make such code use the existing ID token.

Answer (score 0):

The `id_token` represents a user authentication event i.e. describes when (and possibly how) the user authenticated in person. Since a token refresh does not mean that the user is present/online/or-even-alive-anymore an `id_token` *should* not be issued, though your mileage may vary across implementations.

Note that the lifetime of the `id_token` as well as the lifetime of the `access_token` are in principle independent of the application session lifetime, which in its turn is (in principle) independent from the SSO session at the Provider.

The access token - possibly refreshed via the refresh token - can be used to obtain information about the user from the userinfo endpoint. The information returned *must* contain a `sub` claim which must then be compared to the `sub` from the original `id_token` (stored in the application session), see: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfoResponse

Comment: I know I can get the sub from /userinfo, but validating it against an idtoken that is no longer valid seems a bit strange, no?

Comment: the expiry on the id_token merely tells you after which the Client should not consume it anymore to create application sessions; but when received in time and an application session was created from it, that session is tied to the browser (unlike the id_token itself) and that user still owns the session, so no